# Linux in QEMU / UTM VM: davfs2 mount works but has root access only

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, mount

Using a Macbook M1 running Ubuntu 20.04 (arm64) under UTM virtualizer (is QEMU based) works fine, but I cannot access the host file system.
I shared a host folder using the UTM interface and that should be accessible via Webdav2 via http://127.0.0.1:9843/ which does work.
Following instructions on a web page https://www.hagemann.ws/blog/linux-mount-webdav-share-using-fstab-and-davfs2.html
resulted in adding a line to `/etc/fstab`

```
http://127.0.0.1:9843/  /mnt/hostdir    davfs,rw,auto,user,rw,uid=1000,gid=135,_netdev
```

uid is my own user and gid is 135 the davfs2 group.
When I run `mount -a` it does mount, but all files are only accessible via root as they are owned by root, despite specifying the uid and gid. I first tried names but to no avail.
I chown'ed /mnt/hostdir to my user and davfs2 group, but after mounting it reverts to root.

When I run `mount` I see the line (among others obviously) telling uid and gid are both 0 (root):

```
http://127.0.0.1:9843/ on /mnt/hostdir type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,max_read=16384,uid=0,gid=0,helper=davfs)
```

Moreover, time stamps of all files are set to today (the time of mounting) rather than the original filemtime.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you see a few log messages with `dmesg` command?

Comment: Well, I finally solved it using `sshfs`. In the cases when davfs2 did work, it was very slow, sshfs is faster. 
````sshfs -o allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000  user@hostname.local:/Users/user /home/user/main````

Then `/home/user/main` is mounted to the home folder of 'user' on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything right, just when you are done doing your setup procedure you need to do this little step as well:

inside your guest os, inside your user, execute the following command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/shared
```